# Poor rendering -- is it because of bad meshing or Blender?

Tags: python, rendering, mesh, faces

I have some data that I want to use Blender to render. They are a bunch of X,Y,Z coordinates. I run a tesselation algorithm (in Matlab) to generate triangular faces. I pass this info to BPY and render the image (shown below).

Are my images looking poor because

a) it is incorrect rendering
b) poor meshing

Any advice on generating a better mesh or rendering would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Rendered Image]

[image: Mesh in Blender]

Comment: please try with ambient occlusion in order to see the render with global light..

Comment: This is interesting. Could you possibly share some more information on how I could go about exploring this using bpy? Thank you.

Comment: Your mesh has major issues, you can actually see the problem in the viewport, so this is not a rendering bug. Instead, you need to clean up your mesh. You can try the Decimate modifier, or you can manually try and clean it up.

Comment: Thank you. I think you are right. Are there blender mesh smoothing modifier? Also, any pointers towards using the Decimate modifier programmatically?

Comment: maybe if you shared a file with the vertex coordinates and face indices we can have a look? Else you haven't given us enough information to answer.